# Proper file.encoding in Jenkins system and in Jenkins' builds

Tags: jenkins, encoding

I've got a problem with setting encoding properties on Jenkins.

On a test Jenkins "System Info" page for master shows `file.encoding = UTF-8` and `sun.jnu.encoding = UTF-8`. The same values are shown on a slave's "System Info" page. `JVM Options` field in slave's configuration doesn't include `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`, but just like I wrote, the encoding in system info is ok. When I run pipeline script on that slave with withMaven method, in logs there is `Default locale: pl_PL, platform encoding: UTF-8`.

On a production Jenkins "System Info" page for master shows `file.encoding = UTF-8` and `sun.jnu.encoding = UTF-8`. However on a slave's "System Info" page both properties have value `ANSI_X3.4-1968`. When I add `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` to `JVM Options` field in slave's configuration `file.encoding = UTF-8`. Runnig the same pipeline script on slave puts to log file `Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: ANSI_X3.4-1968`. I can set `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` as a `mavenOpts` (withMaven method parameter) and it works.

All servers, both masters and slaves, test and production, are CentOS 8. On both environments I'm using the same version of JDK and Maven, both installed automatically by Jenkins.
`locale` command returns the same on all of them:

```
LANG=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

I noticed that there are some differences on slave's "System Info" page in "Environment Variables" section. On test Jenkins there are more properties. On production Jenkins there aren't: `LANG`, `LESSOPEN`, `S_COLORS`.

My questions:

1. Why do I have to set `file.encoding` in `JVM Options` for slaves in production Jenkins? Somehow it works ok without it on test Jenkins.
2. Why do I have to set `file.encoding` in withMaven calling? Again, somehow it works ok without it on test Jenkins.
3. Why there are differences within environment variables between Jenkins instances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the fact, there weren't created files `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` in user jenkins homedir on slave's servers. After creating them and restarting Jenkins, everything works fine.